# How to get a image of a document rotated so text is in line?

Tags: c#, jquery, ocr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image processing - rotate scanned document to align text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749915/image-processing-rotate-scanned-document-to-align-text)

I working on a project where I have scan with a document scanner some documents but the documents can easy be not in line so text is in some angle so my OCR tools not recognize the text.

So what I want is in C# or jQuery get the angle to rotate the image to, to get the right angle I think something need to analyse the image line by line to se if the text is in line.

I hope someone understand the problem, my english is not the best.

Some ideas?

Comment: If you are planning on manually guessing the angle then the easiest solution would be to use ImageMagick from the commandline. If you hope to automate it then good luck: if the OCR tools can't do it then it must be quite the problem to solve.

Answer (score 0):

i haven't complete my work on this.

I have taken reference from below project.

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/

May be this will help.

Comment: The link may be good but I don't understand the rest.

Comment: I don't understand the rest???

Comment: You haven't completed your work on what?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/

Uploading documents using Optical Character Recognition (OCR)

its a kind of tricky thing but it works for me...
 success rate is about 90%.

Comment: you also dont need to worry about alignment, it convert text smartly, but i only only try 1 line text per image as i only need one line from from image.